# How to call multiple functions when using onRowClick in datatable?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, css, datatable

I have a table with rows and want to highlight the selected row and render row details underneath the table when that row is clicked. I'm currently using method from [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31380/highlight-single-selected-row-in-table) which I will copy below. The problem is that only the highlighting is working but not the rendering. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<script>
var lastRow;
function highlight(elem){
    if(lastRow != undefined)
        lastRow.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    lastRow = elem;
}
</script>
```

Then I do:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!list1}" var="item" rules="rows" id="myTable1" onRowClick="highlight(this);">
```

and

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onRowClick" action="{!showDetail}" reRender="detailBlock" status="appStatus">

apex:param name="rowId" value="{!r.singleRow.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedRowId}" />

</apex:actionSupport>
```

Comment: is your showDetail method being called?

Comment: can you paste your detailBlock that you are trying to rerender? better help would be to post the vf page if it is short.

Comment: @AslamK the showDetail method is not being called. I suspect that it is because onRowClick is already being used in the same block by the highlight. Is there some way to solve this? To Rao: I don't think it has to do with the detailBlock that I'm rendering because if I remove the onRowClick="highlight(this);, the detailBlock renders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will work if you change you `actionSupport` to `actionfunction` with name (let's say `renderTheRow`) and in you highlight method you can call `renderTheRow` in the end.

OR alternatively you can call highlight function in `onsubmit` attribute of `actionfunction`

The reason I think it is not working is because you have already defined handler for the event onRowClick.

When you remove the highlight function, the event handler from actionSupport takes over.

Comment: I ended up just calling the highlight function in onsubmit attribute of actionSupport. Thanks for the suggestion!